# How can we find out in which element in an array the address and value came from in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

For example: `int a[4] = {2, 4, 34}`

Lets say the address of `a[0]` is at `2000` and we know the value of the element at `a[0]` is `2`.

Given only a memory address and a value of an element, is it possible to determine the position of the element in the array?

If so, please provide an example on how to do this.

Comment: A bit unclear what you are asking for. Do you just want to find out the position of an element in the array?

Comment: Are you asking if you can search an array looking for an element? This is easy. But if you have an arbitrary memory address and want to find out if it's part of an array, this is much harder.

Comment: `(AddressOfElement - ArrayBaseAddress) / SizeOfOneElement == Index`

Comment: @WorldSEnder I would say he wants to know which element is at Y if he knows X (the memory address of the first element, 2000 here). He wrote "By just knowing the memory address and the value in", but just the address is enough to determine the index if you know the type and the address of the first element. Pretty much what deviantfan answered.

Comment: @deviantfan the compiler handles the type sizes if the pointers are typed.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for? Just using some pointer arithmetic;

```
int main ()
{
    int ary[] = { 1, 2, 3, 5 };

    int * address_of_2 = &ary[ 1 ];

    int index_of_2 = address_of_2 - ary;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The memory location will be unique for each element in the array. So yes, if you know the memory location, you can iterate through the array and simply find when the reference equals your value.

```
for (int i=0; i < arr_size; i++) {
     if (&arr[i] == address && arr[i] == *address) {
        cout << i << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work, and also proposes an `O(N)` solution to an `O(1)` problem.

Comment: It was not asked about complexity. However, the code is not proper, that's true.

Comment: I edited your answer Jack. When you approve it will be correct. Whereas the second condition I added was necessary to be able to edit your answer (I needed more characters).

Comment: Bold claim, @Elyasin, considering we don't even know what the question is yet.

Comment: I think that is the question: "Given only a memory address and a value of an element, is it possible to determine the position of the element in the array?"

Answer (score 0):

If given an array, the size of the array and type of element(i.e. integer), than yes, given also the address of an element and the value, you could sort through the array and find its position.  Note the significance that the array block is contiguous.

```
array = array;
n = sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array);
oAddress = array;
fAddress = array + n * sizeof(*array);

locOfElement = (elementAddress - oAddress) / (fAddress - oAddress) * n;
```